# Spark Dataframe OOM error when writing into Hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-hive

I have an application used to put Spark dataframe data into Hive.

The first time, the application use 100 cores and 10 GB of memory producing this OutOfMemory error after leaking a lot of 32 Mb chunks.

[image: this OutOfMemory error]

After that I run the application with 100 cores and 20GB of memory obtaining a different leak size (64 Mb) followed by the same OutOfMemory error:

[image: same OutOfMemory error]

Can anyone help me understand this behaviour?

Comment: why don't just increase Memory? did you try monitoring the servers to see how much memory they use? you should also mention how you configured driver and executors memory and cores. this could also point out the problem

Comment: Reformatted/rephrased whole question